# How to update variables in ng-include view

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and a view that shows data from that form. I want to separate form and view (which will be more that one).

Here is my code:

```
<div data-ng-controller="dataController" class="container">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include="templates.simple" scope="data"></div>
</div>
```

And the included view shows initial data good, but does not react on any data change. How do I fix it?

`data` is and object with some fields.
`templates.simple` is a scope variable with template url

Code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ibrsBaq8osYuEODGiM6O

Comment: could you create plunkr of the same?

Comment: @PankajParkar, attached plunkr link

Comment: Check its done now..Thanks :)

Comment: Accepted answer is so wrong.. Do read our discussion in comments..if you really care about right answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason why binding is not working is you are reinitalizing an `createDataController` which is again creating `data` object for that `ng-view` template. This could be solve by removing `createDataController` controller from route.

**Code**

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'form.html',
         //controller: 'createDataController'
    })
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/um7o1FMrnnjIFksoUTa6?p=preview)

**Update**

Other way would be if you want to load your controller twice still it doen't make any sense though. You could do this by writing ng-init on outside div, Instead of declaring that variable from controller.

```
<div data-ng-controller="createDataController" ng-init="data = {name: 'texy'}">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <div data-ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5sBaTgyLajKB8n9S5zD?p=preview)

Comment: Nop... the issue is the scope of controller. The form is inside the ng-view and the template is out side, your exemple doesn't work at all

Comment: @Fals what is relation of form.. its all about prototypal inheritance. Take a look at updated answer

Comment: ng-view create a new scope and discard the parent one. If you don't define the property, as you did to fix the issue, the ng-view will exists isolated from the top controller.

Comment: @Fals I think you are new to angularJs.. see this API and tell me where does `ng-view` creates a isolated scope. Also please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs this will tell you how prototypal inheritance work in javascript

Comment: I will not get into this discussion! You solve the issue your way, and I solve using my way! And, at all we helped someone with something. And... well I Have only 2 years of angular, learning.

Comment: @Fals that not about solving the issue. its about you are sharing wrong knowledge without looking at the things.. Thats not really fair dude..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82874/discussion-between-fals-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: @Fals why you downvoted again? As its correct answer..please read the docs before answering..

Comment: Don't take stuff personal, The inheritance is the right awnsear! You are right! i did look the doc as you suggested! Thank you! https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-view

Comment: @Fals Kindly remove downvote. I took it personally because you did downvoted without knowing mine answer is correct..If you want point then I will upvote yours answer..but do care the OP and other person who are referring to the answer..Sharing wrong explaination is strictly prohibited here.

Comment: @PankajParkar is there a chance to avoid using ng-init, as the objects usully are much bigger than one property

Comment: @Ivan first you tell me why you want to load controller twice?

Comment: @PankajParkar I am not trying to load controller twice, but I basically need two different views for the same controller